# Prevent navigating to the same fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using Android navigation jetpack library with BottomNavigationView. I have implemented the NavHost, the NavGraph and my fragments. Everything is working as intented when I use actions to navigate.

I use the following code to setup everything:

```
 val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host)
 bottom_navigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

The problem is that if I click a tab 2 times the fragment is recreated twice. Is there any way to intercept navigation? I don't want to navigate to the same fragment that's being shown.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124538620),

> Feel free to set a [OnNavigationItemReselectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener), which takes precedence over the `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` set by NavigationUI.

```
val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host)
bottom_navigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
bottom_navigation.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {
  // Do nothing to ignore the reselection
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to fix the recreation. But if I navigate from fragment A to B inside the same selected tab, clicking again this tab should navigateUp to fragment A and it doesn't. I could set a NavigationItemSelectedListener with some checkings but this will screw up `bottom_navigation.setupWithNavController(navController)`purpose. I'm i missing something?

Comment: If you have custom logic you want to do when reselecting (such as calling `navController.popBackStack(it.itemId, false)` to go back to the first screen of that tab), then you'd want to put that logic in your reselection listener rather than doing nothing.

Comment: thanks so much for this. I didn't know there was even listeners available for BottomNavigationView.

Comment: Tanks so much, I spent time searching for these keywords

Comment: sorry but for my this didnt worked. I'm facing the mentioned problem, but with `setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener{ navController.popBackStack(it.itemId, false) }` the fragment is recreated after navigation from A to B when navigate back to A by pressing bottom tab. Because the `setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener ` isnt fired in this case. Could you guys help me please?

Answer (score 4):

inside *setOnItemSelectedListener* use :

```
if( item.getItemId() == navController.getCurrentDestination().getId()){  return true; }
```

because OnNavigationItemSelectedListener is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

I write this extension. It will check current fragment with destinations and if both are same, it will only close drawer. But there is a some animation problem while closing drawer.

```
fun NavigationView.setupWithUniqueFragment(navController: NavController) {

    this.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(object : NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            val parent = this@setupWithUniqueFragment.parent
            if (item.itemId == navController.currentDestination?.id) {
                if (parent is DrawerLayout) {
                    parent.closeDrawer(this@setupWithUniqueFragment, true)
                }
                return true
            }
            val handled = NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
            if (handled) {
                if (parent is DrawerLayout) {
                    parent.closeDrawer(this@setupWithUniqueFragment, true)
                }
            }
            return handled
        }

    })

    val weakReference = WeakReference<NavigationView>(this@setupWithUniqueFragment)
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(
        object : NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener {
            override fun onDestinationChanged(
                controller: NavController,
                destination: NavDestination, arguments: Bundle?
            ) {
                val view = weakReference.get()
                if (view == null) {
                    navController.removeOnDestinationChangedListener(this)
                    return
                }
                val menu = view.menu
                var h = 0
                val size = menu.size()
                while (h < size) {
                    val item = menu.getItem(h)
                    item.isChecked = matchDestination(destination, item.itemId)
                    h++
                }
            }
        })
}

internal fun matchDestination(
    destination: NavDestination,
    @IdRes destId: Int
): Boolean {
    var currentDestination: NavDestination? = destination
    while (currentDestination!!.id != destId && currentDestination.parent != null) {
        currentDestination = currentDestination.parent
    }
    return currentDestination.id == destId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem where I am using an About page (using the really good AboutLibraries), and it would stack up duplicate pages.  I ended up doing this in my OnOptionsItemSelected method

```
            case R.id.action_about:
            NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController( this, R.id.nav_host_fragment );
            if ( navController.getCurrentDestination().getId() != R.id.nav_about )
            {
                navController.navigate( R.id.nav_about );
            }
```

And now it only shows a single fragment and won't stack the same one ontop.  It's a shame this behaviour couldn't be defined in the XML and I needed to do this in code.